# Adding a <script> to the document causes it not to load the rest of the document

Tags: html, css

I have added a script to the document, the script shows the name of the day of the week in French, if I add the script it will not load the whole document, just the result of the script, removing the script content restores the document function.

Update:

This is a HTML document, the users clicks on the menus:

```
<li><a id="page7">Software</a></li>
```

This calls a inner script:

```
<div id="result">

<script src="./docu2_files/jquery.js" type="text/javascript">

</script>        
</div>
```

This action will load a jquery, who loads content in the main index:

```
$("#page7").click(function(){
        $('#result').load('./docu2_files/docs/software.html');
       });
```

CSS

```
#fixed {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 200px;
    border: 3px solid black;
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}
```

The script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var d=new Date()
    var weekday=new Array("Dimanche - Domingo","Lundi - Lunes","Mardi - Martes","Mercredi - Mi?oles","Jeudi - Jueves",
                "Vendredi - Viernes","Samedi S?do")
    document.write("Hoy es: " + weekday[d.getDay()])
</script>
```

Comment: Use document.getElementByID('date').innerHTML = "Hoy es: " + weekday[d.getDay(); and create a div with the id "date".

Comment: Could you please provide a working snippet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The write() method is mostly used for testing: If it is used after an HTML document is fully loaded, **it will delete all existing HTML**.

`document.getElementById('fixed').innerHTML = "Hoy es: " + weekday[d.getDay()];`

Comment: var d=new Date()
    var weekday=new Array("Dimanche - Domingo","Lundi - Lunes","Mardi - Martes","Mercredi - Mi?oles","Jeudi - Jueves",
                "Vendredi - Viernes","Samedi S?do")
    document.getElementByID('fixed').innerHTML = Hoy es: " + weekday[d.getDay()])


Content is showing again, but is not showing me the echo...i don't know where i'm failing

Comment: @JoseVieirosMoreno `document.getElementById('fixed').innerHTML = "Hoy es: " + weekday[d.getDay()];` Javascript is Case-sensitive, so *ID* 
 in getElementById must have big *I* and small *d* (it was my fault, i write it wrong, sorry)